# Change color for the class using different css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have one of the classes in my game change color so I used a different css files for each color. The stylesheets are in a folder called `stylesheets`. I used the script below to make it simple and short and be useable for all colors but it the color doesn't change. I believe the problem is with the href link. Is there a problem with my script?

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateColor(filename) {
        $('head').children(":last").append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/" + filename + ".css" />');
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('blue')">Blue</option>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('black')">Black</option>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('gray')">Gray</option>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('green')">Green(Default)</option>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('pink')">Pink</option>
  <option href="javascript:updateColor('yellow')">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$('head').children(":last").append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/' + filename + '.css" />');` - yes your string concatenation is not proper

Comment: Instead of trying to dynamically add a CSS file to change the color of a class you should instead have a class for each color and change the class of the element when buttons are clicked.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it took me a moment to play spot the difference :) OP, look at the quotes being used

Comment: @ArunPJohny I understand the issue there but this still doesn't work on my code. I think this script is not updating the css stylesheet with dropdown. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to output a link tag in the head that has your default stylesheet in it. It looks like that is green from your example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="color-changer" href="stylesheets/green.css">
```

Then change your select to be:

```
<select>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="gray">Gray</option>
  <option value="green" selected>Green(Default)</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Then your js becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('#color-changer').attr('href','stylesheets/' + $(this).val() + '.css') ;
    });
});
```

If you would like to stick with the approach of appending new stylesheets, you can use the following js:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/' + $(this).val() + '.css" />') ;
    });
});
```

Comment: filename is not defined

Comment: Works like a charm... Before I select this as the best answer I want to know is there another way without declaring the `id="color-changer"` link tag like something closer to my approach in the question?

Comment: Adding the id allows you to remove the previous stylesheet from the document. This gives the added benefit of cleaning up any styles that may not be completely overridden in the new stylesheet. I supposed you could just assume that the last link tag in the head will be the correct one and edit it

Answer (score 0):

href="stylesheets/' + filename + '.css"

should work because you started making the append with a ' and so the " didn't stop it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your concatenation is slightly wrong. You also need some type of event to your JQuery such as change, or click. It may be a problem with the relative path within your `href` path. Based on what you have now, the `stylesheets` directory would need to be in the same directory as your HTML file.

One approach is to create a new stylesheet link for every selection which may work better because then there is no traversing within `head`.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="color">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
    <option value="green">Green(Default)</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#color').on('change', function (e) {
    var selected = $("option:selected", this);
    var color = this.value;
    $('head').append
     ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/' + color + '.css" />');
});
```

I believe there is a big issue with this whole approach though, once user leaves the page (or refreshes) your link will disappear unless you use LocalStorage (HTML5 only) or cookies. Might be OK in your situation though. I would highly recommend using PHP for this if possible which IMO is more manageable in this situation.